# Edit to add syntax highlighting on a codeblock rejected

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I'm not sure how anyone could reasonably judge that the addition of syntax highlighting doesn't make a post easier to read, so I was rather surprised by this edit being rejected for that reason. These changes are not superfluous, as they make the code much easier to read.

Here is the edit in question:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23757090

Can anyone explain to me why the edit was rejected, and if there is some way for it to be accepted instead.

Comment: I don't think I would consider syntax highlighting a real improvement. Without it the answer is still understandable. If you try it anyway instead of *Added syntax highlighting for code blocks* say something like *The tags on the question don't have a syntax-highlighter so to make this python code look better added the language hint and changed from indented code blocks to code fenced code blocks* but then it is still a lottery. You win some, you lose some. Let's move on.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is slightly helpful, but trivial. If that's *all* you want to do, better to wait until having full edit privileges than to have something like that go through the queue

Comment: It definitely improves the answer. And it doesn't ignore any other problems with the post. I really see no reason to reject such an edit.

Comment: I'm with @BDL the syntax highlighting *does* improve the post. No other glaring errors are left, either, so the rejection seems like a bad step. The argument "but you can understand it even without the change" doesn't hold water, I think - you don't need grammar or any capital letters and the post would be *understandable*. It doesn't look good and I am pretty sure that the consensus is that it can and should be improved. I would personally apply the same standards to syntax highlighting - it can and should be improved.